# As a non-Finnish citizen, am I subject to income-based traffic fines if the traffic violation occurred in Finland?

Tags: automobiles, finland, traffic, fines

I read on https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2015/03/finland-home-of-the-103000-speeding-ticket/387484/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190622025349/https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2015/03/finland-home-of-the-103000-speeding-ticket/387484/))  that most of Scandinavia determines fines based on income. E.g.:

> In 2002, a Nokia executive was fined the equivalent of $103,000 for going 45 in a 30 zone on his motorcycle.

As a non-Finnish citizen and residing outside Finland most of the year, am I subject to income-based traffic fines if the traffic violation occurred in Finland? If so, how do the Finnish authorities find out my income?